# Unable to Uninstall JRuby on Windows

Tags: java, ruby

I'm unable to uninstall JRuby on Windows.

When I run the uninstallation program the first time it finishes its work with an error: [java.io.IOException: access denied](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20481401/github/jruby_uninstall_access_denied.png), also it deletes the *files.log* file from the installation folder. When I run it the second time it fails with another error: [java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\jruby-1.7.13\install4j\files.log](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20481401/github/jruby_uninstall_missing_file.png) because at the first time it deleted this file.

[Here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20481401/github/install4j_error.log)'s the content of the *error.log* file which is created after unsuccessful uninstallation.

How can I uninstall JRuby?

---

Windows 7

JRuby 1.7.13

JRE 8.0.250

Install4j

Comment: Are you administrator of the machine? Can you run as administrator?

Comment: Did you try repairing the installation before uninstalling?

Comment: Yes, I'm an administrator. What do you mean by "repairing the installation"?

Comment: When you try to "install" again the product, there is an option to "repair/modify" ? If so, do it, and then execute the uninstaller again with admin access.

Comment: Unfortunately, It doesn't work.